# Android ContentResolver.NotifyChange() not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, phone-call, android-contentresolver

First, I read call logs, move to first row, and get row id.

Then I update the row using content resolver using row id as query string. I do this to change last call log to some other number.

```
Android.Database.ICursor cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.Date + " DESC limit 1;");
cursor.MoveToFirst();
string queryString = "_ID='" + cursor.GetInt(37) + "'";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put(CallLog.Calls.Number, ActiveCallMonitor.realcaller);
values.Put(CallLog.Calls.CachedNormalizedNumber, ActiveCallMonitor.realcaller);
values.Put(CallLog.Calls.New, 1);
Application.Context.ContentResolver.Update(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, values, queryString, null); 

var returnUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, id);
Application.Context.ContentResolver.NotifyChange(returnUri, null);
```

Now this change will show in apps that read call logs every time. But other apps like Truecaller show same old call logs because they only only listen to changes in database. Which Eventually means that NotifyChange is not working.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, it's hard to locate the problem.Would you please share the steps so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I am not an expert in android, but I think above mentioned code is enough to reproduce. Nothing is missing in this.

Comment: `But other apps like Truecaller show same old call logs because they only only listen to changes in database.` Where are the call logs？ And how other apps like Truecaller read the call logs?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT As per my testing, they listen to changes in call logs database.

Comment: Based on the limited information there could be multiple sources of error. Apps who listen for changes typically use the [ContentResolver.registerContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContentResolver?hl=en#registercontentobserver) API. Have you tried notifying a different URI? E.g. `Application.Context.ContentResolver.NotifyChange(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null);`

Comment: @MarkusHi yes I tried that first.

Comment: It's really hard to locate the problem just based on your code. Your code above should be in your APP, so you can post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that it will help us address the problem.